# PyQt - Custom Widget Disappears when added with Alignment

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qgridlayout

I'm having an issue where a custom widget I am making appears just fine when added to a QGridLayout without specifying an alignment, but when I specify an Alignment it disappears.

Here is the custom widget:

```
class OutlineLabel(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.text = text

    def paintEvent(self, event=None):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        path = QPainterPath()
        pen = QPen();
        font = QFont("Helvetica", 14, 99, False)
        brush = QBrush(QtCore.Qt.white)
        pen.setWidth(1);
        pen.setColor(QtCore.Qt.black);
        painter.setFont(font);
        painter.setPen(pen);
        painter.setBrush(brush)
        path.addText(0, 20, font, self.text); 
        painter.drawPath(path);
```

Here is an example where it will display just fine:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
wnd = QWidget()
wnd.resize(400,400)
grid = QGridLayout()
test = OutlineLabel("hello")
grid.addWidget(test, 0, 0)
wnd.setLayout(grid)
wnd.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But if I change it to the following, it no longer shows:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
wnd = QWidget()
wnd.resize(400,400)
grid = QGridLayout()
test = OutlineLabel("hello")
grid.addWidget(test, 0, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
wnd.setLayout(grid)
wnd.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Is there some information I need to set in the OutlineLabel class to work correctly with Alignments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a problem with size hint (your widget is empty).

If you reimplement the `sizeHint()` method to return a valid `QSize`, your widget should appear:

```
def sizeHint( self ):
    return QSize( 200, 200 )
```