# How do you add a PlotWidget to the CentralWidget of a MainWindow with PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I am building a simply GUI with PyQt5 - the goal is to open a directory which is filled with data files and automatically make a plot from each file, with arrow buttons that let me click through the files, generating a plot for each one. Essentially, a simple visual data browser.

I have a MainWindow where I define a centralWidget with a layout (QVBoxLayout). I can add several widgets to this centralWidget and have them appear (my dummy color widgets in the code below). However, as soon as I try to add my plotWidget, all the color widgets disappear and I can only see the plot. Any suggestions on how I can make the PlotWidget and other widgets all show up in the vertical layout?

This is my code as is, it runs but produces only the plot. If you comment out `layout.addWidget(self.graphWidget)` it shows the four color widgets.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget, plot
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPalette, QColor
import sys
import os

os.environ['QT_MAC_WANTS_LAYER'] = '1'
# to make dummy color widgets
class Color(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, color):
        super(Color, self).__init__()
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        palette = self.palette()
        palette.setColor(QPalette.Window, QColor(color))
        self.setPalette(palette)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        # make graph widget
        self.graphWidget = pg.PlotWidget()
        #self.setCentralWidget(self.graphWidget)

        # graph styling things
        time = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        counts = [1, 3, 7, 2, 9, 4, 10, 5, 12]
        self.graphWidget.setTitle("Plot title", color="k", size="18pt")
        self.graphWidget.setBackground('w')
        pen = pg.mkPen(color=(0, 102, 255), width=2)
        self.data_line = self.graphWidget.plot(time, counts, pen=pen)
        styles = {'color':'r', 'font-size':'18px'}
        self.graphWidget.setLabel('left', 'Counts', **styles)
        self.graphWidget.setLabel('bottom', 'Time (s)', **styles)
        pen = pg.mkPen(color=(0, 0, 0), width=2)
        self.graphWidget.plotItem.getAxis('left').setPen(pen)
        self.graphWidget.plotItem.getAxis('bottom').setPen(pen)
        self.graphWidget.plotItem.getAxis('right').setPen(pen)
        self.graphWidget.plotItem.getAxis('top').setPen(pen)
        self.graphWidget.getAxis('left').setTextPen('k')
        self.graphWidget.getAxis('bottom').setTextPen('k')

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)

        layout.addWidget(self.graphWidget)
        layout.addWidget(Color('red'))
        layout.addWidget(Color('green'))
        layout.addWidget(Color('blue'))
        layout.addWidget(Color('red'))

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Update: I tried adding

```
def sizeHint( self ):
    return QSize( 100, 30 )
```

as suggested by @musicamante and the related question here:
[PyQt - Custom Widget Disappears when added with Alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20462895/pyqt-custom-widget-disappears-when-added-with-alignment)

However, adding the sizeHint changes the size of the window when it initally opens to be small, but when I drag it larger it still is only the plot, taking up the whole space. I also tried setMinimumWidth() and implementing this for both the plot and one of the color widgets to the same value, but this also didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: You need to at least override [`sizeHint()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizeHint-prop) that returns a proper size (eg. `return QSize(100, 30)`). Alternatively, explicitly call `setMinimumWidth()`, `setMinimumHeight()` or `setMinimumSize()`. Without any of that, any widget that can expand (which is typical of scroll areas like pyqtgraph plots, which inherits from QGraphicsView) will take all available space that is not reclaimed by other widgets. Since by default QWidget returns an invalid size (as explained in the documentation linked above), this allows the plot to occupy the whole area.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @musicamante I updated my question, still having trouble even when I tied ``sizeHint()`` and ``setMinimumWidth()``

Comment: You didn't add `def sizeHint()` to `MainWindow`, did you? The size hint has to be that of the widget, so you have to add that override to the `Color` subclass... Besides, your issue is with the *height*, because you're adding widgets to a *vertical* layout, so you should have used `setMinimumHeight()`.